# Convert captured Image to Base64 String

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to save an image to the server by sending a base64 string to the server but it keeps giving me an error message on the server reading "Illegal base64 character a".
Below is the snippet of the code:

```
ImageIO img = ImageIO.getImageIO();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
img.save(et, out, ImageIO.FORMAT_PNG, 1);
byte[] ba = out.toByteArray();                          
userImage64=Base64.encode(ba);
```

et is the image I am converting to base64 string and userImage64 is the string I am sending to the server. What could be the issue that is causing that error?

Comment: This should work just fine. Notice that the Base64 class has more than one encode method (with line length limits) so maybe your server expects that mode.

Comment: Yes. I actually changed the encode method and it worked just fine. Thank you